# To solveBrowser conflict in firefox for our portal

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

we are developing a social networking portal ..but in the registration form we had browser conflict in radio button in firefox.

when the gender option is selected and changed its getting hide in firefox which is stable in chrome.i tried to solve by changing css but it dint help me.

still the problem exists.

can anyone have any idea of this problem???

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Perhaps the HTML/CSS code for the form would help to shed some light on your problem.  Is it live somewhere for us to look at?

Comment: the site s in development process so i should not tell server address...css div id given as                                                            #gender div ul{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size: 18px;
/*height:95px;
dth:95px;*/
}                                                                   #gender div ul li{
float: left;
margin-right:20px;
} i am using symfony widget to get the input values

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with Mootools Selector with the new Firefox.

Moreover, I have social network portal and recent firefox upgrade caused no editor in registration, post news and other user input areas to be missing. 
It works perfectly in all other browsers and no changes to the site to cause a conflict. Other developers have same issue.
I'm not sure if this will assist http://www.simbunch.com/blog/127-problem-with-mootools-selector-with-the-new-firefox